# How does google chrome manage its popup blocking policy?

Tags: google-chrome

It seems like pretty much random behavior to me, cause some sites are allowed for `window.open` commands and the new window/tab is opened without any problem (I never add them to the whitelist in my settings), but some other URLs will show me the popup blocker message.

Can you tell about the way chrome takes those decisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like when I just type `window.open` in the DevTools it's not considered to be a popup, and a new tab is opened. If the `window.open` is a part of a function and I call it, the popup management will take action and it's going to be blocked unless the website is whitelisted.